# KeyError in python saying KeyError : 'value'

Tags: python, python-requests, lxml.html

I am trying to get the hidden elements in twitter login page. I followed a procedure which simply gets the hidden elements in that page. But the problem is when i try to get value of those elements, i am getting key error. the code is:

```
    import requests, lxml.html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = requests.session()
login = s.get('https://twitter.com/login')
login_html = lxml.html.fromstring(login.text)
hidden_inputs = login_html.xpath(r'//form//input[@type="hidden"]')
form = {x.attrib["name"]: x.attrib["value"] for x in hidden_inputs}
print(form)
```

I am getting error at x.attrib['value']. How to rectify this?

Comment: `x.attrib.get('value')` or use a contition if you don't want `None` values.

Comment: `print([x.attrib.keys() for x in hidden_inputs])`, before the line that throws the exception, to see what keys you can specify. Or to make it error proof `x.attrib.get("value", "not exist!!!")`.

Comment: The hidden fields do not have any value element which is why you are getting the error.

Comment: @CristiFati That is _not_ error-proofing. That is error-obscuring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of (some) the objects you will get:

```
<InputElement 1a62c5ef778 name='ui_metrics' type='hidden'>
```

There is no "value" key.

If you print this:

```
for x in hidden_inputs:
     print(x.attrib)
```

Then you will be able to see which tags have values:

```
{'type': 'hidden', 'name': 'authenticity_token', 'value': '7fca6a14828cd425dad8437cc291687fc2ff1f96'}
```

So you will have to explicitly check for the ones that do have values

Comment: But when i view the page source of twitter login i am unable to find that value which you have mentioned

Comment: Insert this into your code before the form and you will see the objects you are receiving back: `for x in hidden_inputs:
    print(x)`

Comment: @AkhilReddy see updated answer, some of the tags do have values

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I use google devtools check twitter login page and get this image. The last 2 inputs either do not have value or it is not key value pair, so I guess that's why you got the error.

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that a member x of hidden_inputs is not a dictionary including the key "value". You should print out hidden_inputs to see its elements, and make sure they are dictionaries that include the key "value".